# ksshaskpass: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, git, fedora

I just started using Linux. So, i am not sure how to handle this. My machine has `ksshaskpass` installed. I was not preferring to use that so i removed it using command:

```
dnf remove kss*
```

It was removed successfully but now when ever i try to communicate to git. It show's me the following error on terminal.

```
fatal: cannot run /usr/bin/ksshaskpass: No such file or directory
```

What i understand is, there is still some link in configuration files which is driving the request to `ksshaskpass`. But i am not sure how to get rid of it.

Comment: You'd have to unset  SSH_ASKPASS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have forgotten about unsetting the SSH_ASKPASS variable,
Do it like,

**Locate the Variable**

```
env | grep -i ask
SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/lib/ssh/ksshaskpass
```

**Set The Variable**

```
cat ~/.bashrc | grep unset
unset SSH_ASKPASS
```